# Data binding parent-child relationships in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

### **The Code:**

I have two classes:

```js
export class Shipment {
    shipmentId: number;
    widget: Widget;

}

export class Widget {
    widgetId: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Then I have a `ShipmentUi` view-model that has an instance of shipment (`this.shipment`).

And in the `ShipmentUi` view I compose part of the UI show the WidgetUi that allows selection of the Widget:

```html
<compose view-model="src/views/widgetUi" model.bind="shipment"></compose>
```

The WigetUi's view-model saves off the shipment.  So WidgetUi has a `this.shipment`.

And then widgetUi's view shows a selector:

```html
<select value.bind="shipment.widget" >
    <option class="dropdown-toggle" repeat.for="widget of widgets"
            model.two-way="widget">${widget.name}</option>
</select>
```

### **The Question Setup:**

In my compose tag (on ShipmentUi's view), I would rather bind to `shipment.widget`.

This would have WidgetUi's view-model only get a `this.widget`.  (The `WidgetUi` class does not need to see or know about the `shipment`.  Its sole function is to allow selecting a `Widget`.  It should not need to care if it is for a shipment or for something else.)

**But, as I understand Javascript, this is not going to work.**

Because if I just pass in the reference to shipment.widget, then WidgetUi will have just a reference to the widget part.  At first WidgetUi's `this.widget` will have the same reference as ShipmentUi's `this.shipment.widget`.

But when the user selects a different widget, WidgetUi `this.widget` will get a different reference (to the newly selected widget in the dropdown).  But ShipmentUi's `this.shipment.widget` will will still reference the original widget.

### **The Question:**

**When binding to child objects in Javascript, do you always have to pass in the containing object if you want to know about swap of the child object?**

The reason for this question is that my tests are not 100% conclusive.  So I am hoping someone can clear it up for me.

I am also hoping I am wrong somehow, as I really don't like the idea of having to expose all the data in the containing classes.  (Giving access to `shipment` in the `WigetUi` class in this case.)

---

### Re-asking (clarification):

Fabio Luz requested some clarification on what I am asking.  So here is an attempt.  This walks through the example above, but changing it to the way I would LIKE it to work.

I have two Widgets.  Sharp Widget and Dull Widget.

**ShipmentUi.js:**
This class has the variable `this.shipment.widget`.  I am going to say that its value is **'A3'** (arbitrary memory value).  'A3' is a reference to a widget that has a name of 'Sharp Widget'.

I then pass the widget down to the WidgetUi class:

```html
<compose view-model="src/views/widgetUi" model.bind="shipment.wiget"></compose>
```

**WidgetUi.js:**
The WidgetUi class has:

```js
activate(widget: Widget) {
   this.widget = widget;
}
```

So now in WidgetUi `this.widget` also has a value of 'A3'.  That value is a memory reference to the Widget that has a name of 'Sharp Widget'.

Now the user uses this `select` element to change the Widget:

```html
<select value.bind="widget" >
    <option class="dropdown-toggle" repeat.for="widget of widgets"
            model.two-way="widget">${widget.name}</option>
</select>
```

This time I bind to `widget` (instead of `this.shipment.widget` like I did above).

Then user picks a widget with the name of 'Dull Widget' using the `select`.  That widget has a value of 'B7'.  And 'B7' is a reference to the widget named 'Dull Widget'.

As I understand JavaScript, WidgetUi's `this.widget` now has a value of 'B7' (which is a reference to 'Dull Widget').  (This is done via the Aurelia data binding system.)

But ShipmentUi's `this.shipment.widget` is still 'A3' (which is a reference to 'Sharp Widget').

This is not what I wanted when I bound `this.shipment.widget` to the `compose` element.  I wanted the updates to the widget object to be reflected in the shipment.  (Note, if I had just updated `widget.name`, then it would have been updated.)

So, from what I can see, I have to pass in the full parent to the `compose` element (`this.shipment` in this case), if I want an assignment to be captured.

I am hoping I am wrong (or there is a workaround), because passing the parent object makes me share details that the "child" class does not need to know about.  (ie it breaks data encapsulation)

I guess I could make a "holder" between each layer of my classes.  For Example: `this.shipment.holder.widget` and `holder` would just have the widget in it.  But this is kinda ugly...  I hope there is another way...

So, my question is: Am I right with my above statements?  **And if I am, is there another way that keeps my object model clean?**

Comment: I see that you put so much effort to make your question clear, but I still don't understand what you are asking =/

Comment: @FabioLuz - I updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you're looking for a way to share the minimum amount of data with the widgetui component. Instead of giving it the whole shipment object so that it can manipulate the `shipment.widget` property, you'd rather give it a property accessor to the widget property.

Good news: this is exactly what `@bindable` is designed to do. All you'll need to do is stop using compose and craft a custom element with `@bindable` properties representing the minimum amount of data the custom element needs to do it's job.  For example:

**widget-picker.js**

```js
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class WidgetPicker {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) widget;
  @bindable widgets;
}
```

**widget-picker.html**

```html
<select value.bind="widget">
  <option repeat.for="widget of widgets" model.bind="widget">${widget.name}</option>
</select>
```

**usage:**

```html
<widget-picker widget.bind="shipment.widget" widgets.bind="widgets"></widget-picker>
```

**Example:**

https://gist.run/?id=4c726da335aaecefd80b

Comment: updated the html and added an example- there was a typo in widget-picker.html