# aurelia-breeze validation with custom elements

Tags: breeze, aurelia, aurelia-breeze

NOTE: This scenario is the same as the one from this question: [Data binding parent-child relationships in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35560880/16241)

## The Code:

**usage:**

```html
<form role="form" id="formShipment" breeze-validation.bind="shipment">
    <widget-picker widget.bind="shipment.widget" widgets.bind="widgets"></widget-picker>
</form>
```

**widget-picker.js**

```js
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class WidgetPicker {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) widget;
  @bindable widgets;
}
```

**widget-picker.html**

```html
<select value.bind="widget">
  <option repeat.for="widget of widgets" model.bind="widget">${widget.name}</option>
</select>

<!-- Some other UI stuff that I would rather not turn red if the above fails validation-->
```

## The Problem:

I am trying to build a componentized UI and have a single control/element that controls selecting a Widget (`widget-picker`).

But I also need to have breeze know that `shipment.widget` is required (and show it on the widget control.)

But there are two things blocking this.

1. In aurelia-validation.js the `subscribe` method only looks at the bindings on the view that has the breeze-validation custom attribute.  This could easily be fixed by looking at the view's controllers views (and get the bindings on that):

`this.view.controllers.forEach(function (controller) { 
   if (controller.view) controller.view.bindings.forEach(function (binding) {
       existingListOfCurrentViewsBindings.push(binding) 
    }) 
 })`

2. But because `shipment.widget` passes through an `@bindable` it does not have a `source` property.  This means that even if aurelia-validation had looked at the child custom elements, the current method of finding the breeze property would fail.

## The Question:

**Is there a way to get aurelia-breeze to support validating into custom elements (on the control that failed)?**

NOTE: I could just have the validation show up in a general validation area, but since most of my UI runs as custom-elements, I would have almost all my UI that way.  This is not nearly as user friendly as something near the control that has failed.

Comment: aurelia-validation is in the middle of a rewrite that will enable this type of scenario. Much of the validation presentation logic in the aurelia-breeze plugin will be removed and instead you'll be able to "plug" breeze validation into aurelia-validation

Comment: @JeremyDanyow cool, good to know. any rough estimate when validation lib will be ready?

Comment: we're targeting having it ready within the next week or two

Comment: @JeremyDanyow - Now that the validation stuff is out, do you know if this is supported?